# React + redux: call dispatch when connected component loads

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am new to react. I have a react + react router + redux app where I want to make a dispatch call from a child component. Right now, the dispatch is happening in my index.js file at the very top of the app, where it loads all the data from the database via a redux thunk action and api call:

```
const store = configureStore();
store.dispatch(loadCourses()); <-- redux thunk function calling api
store.dispatch(loadAuthors());

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
       <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

What if I want to load the data, or be able to refresh it, when my (connected) child component below loads?

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as courseActions from '../../actions/courseActions';
import CourseList from './CourseList';
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';


class CoursesPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.redirectToAddCoursePage = this.redirectToAddCoursePage.bind(this);
    }

    redirectToAddCoursePage() {
        browserHistory.push('/ReactJS/course');
    }

    render() {
        const {courses} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="page-header">
                    <h3>Courses</h3>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="New Course" className="btn btn-default btn-toolbar pull-right" onClick={this.redirectToAddCoursePage} />
                <div className="panel panel-default ">
                    <div className="panel-heading">
                        <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    </div>
                    <CourseList courses={courses} />
                </div>
            </div>        
        );
    }
}

CoursesPage.propTypes = {
    courses: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        courses: state.courses
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(courseActions, dispatch),
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CoursesPage);
```

It seems to me the way it is set up currently (from a tutorial I followed) that loading ALL the data from the entire database when the app starts up is inefficient, especially if there could be thousands of rows of data in multiple tables.

So if I wanted to call `store.dispatch(loadCourses())` from this component when it loads, where would it go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably want to call this in the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method of your component. From the docs:

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Answer (score 1):

If you grab your actions in your component as props and call them directly when you need them:

```
class CoursePage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    // ...
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this) // available to click in component with proper scope set
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    // called before component inits (only once)
    // this would be your first load, rather than calling it right
    // after you create your store
    this.props.loadCourses()
  }

  handleClick() {
    // click handler
    this.props.loadCourses();
  }

  // ...

  render() {
    // ... the rest of your component
     <button onClick={handleClick}>Refresh data</button>
    // ... the rest of your component

}
```

Comment: You want to avoid using the `componentWillMount()` lifecycle method to make API calls, setup event listeners, etc.

Comment: I combined your two answers, using componentDidMount and the example code above. This worked to solve one of my problems (not loading everything when the app inits) but it didn't solve the other problem I was hoping it would (and didn't mention). I have a nested component (author) for each course that, after saving a course and being redirected to the course list view, is giving me a null value error for the author object (showing the first and last name in the list). That may have to be another post though...

Comment: Looks like you're on the right track. If you haven't yet, I would read up on [container vs presentational components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0). Ideally, you wouldn't do any data fetching in a presentational component.